# Is it possible to control iPhone application icon and price by country?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Im looking to launch my game worldwide, but would like to be able to change the icon based on region.  (Specifically the east vs west)  Our game sold great in Japan last year, but the icon (which had a very Japanese anime style) affected our sales in the US, despite the core gameplay being different.

Is it possible to change the icon or price by region?  I couldn't see how in iTunesConnnect and had trouble finding any information.

Furthermore, if it is not possible, would Apple reject 2 version of the app with the given changes, provided the regions do not overlap?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is answered somewhere on the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can just rebuild the app with a different icon and bundle identifier and create a new app entry in itunesconnect for each region you want to change the icon/price for.

Comment: So you mean like a seperate app ID and everything?  Is there a way around this?  With in-app purchase it would be nice not to have to go that route.  If not the price, at least being able to change the icon.

Comment: Thats the only way I can think to do it, since the icon is built into the app, before you even determine where or how it is going to be distributed